# Google classroom API returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use the Google classroom API to show the coursework of a particular course. I called this API:

```
"https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/{courseid}/courseWork"
```

But the server returned this error:

```
"Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
```

This API is for a chrome extension. I've checked the manifest file:

```
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": some id
    "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses",
               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me"]
}
```

I also checked the developer console, the scopes section also contains the above URLs.

Does anyone know what am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: The courses api works fine, but the coursework api returns a 403 insufficient authentication scopes error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I've solved the puzzle myself! I had to reload the unpacked extension to let the new manifest file take effect.

Comment: unpacked extension? can you explain more